# Keep first 3 characters of every word containing a character

Tags: awk, sed

I have a large text file with lines like:

```
01    81118   9164.47    0/0:6,0:6:18:.:.:0,18,172:.   0/0:2,0:2:6:.:.:0,6,74:.  0/1:4,5:9:81:.:.:148,0,81:.
```

What I need is to keep just the first three characters of all the columns containing a colon, i.e.

```
01  81118   9164.47  0/0  0/0  0/1
```

Where the number of chars after the first 3 can vary. I started here by removing everything after a colon, but that removes the entire rest of the line, rather than per word:
`sed 's/:.*//g' file.txt`

Alternately, I've been trying to bring in the word boundary (\b) and hack away at removing everything after colons several times:

```
sed 's/\b:[^ ]//g' file.txt | sed 's/\b:[^ ]//g'
```

But this is not a good way to go about it. What's the best approach?

Comment: Why don't you use awk for this?

Comment: Very open to awk, too! Had just been trying to get better with sed is all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using GNU `sed` with regular expression extensions, a one-liner could be:

```
sed -E 's/(\S{3})\S*:\S*/\1/g' file
```

`\S` matches non-whitespace characters (a GNU extension).

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk`. Print only 3 first characters of any field containing colon, print the rest as is.

```
awk '{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i ~/:/) $i=substr($i,1,3) } 1' file
```

- `substr()` is one of the [GNU awk string functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html).
- `1` at the end of the statement is equivalent to action `{print}` the whole line.

---

Regarding output format, if input is tab separated and you want to keep the tabs, you can run:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS="\t"} { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i ~/:/) $i=substr($i,1,3) } 1' file
```

or another idea is to pretty-print with `column -t` (does not insert real `\t` but appropriate number of spaces between fields)

```
awk '{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i ~/:/) $i=substr($i,1,3) } 1' file |column -t
```

Comment: Nice! This works. Is there any way for this not to replace my tabs with spaces?

Comment: @noam42 if your input contains tabs then please update your question to state that and state where they are. The sample code you posted only handles blanks, not tabs, so as of now your question looks like there are no tabs in your input.

Comment: @Ed Morton it's OK, i have updated with a simple way on how to keep tabs. Formatted code in SO has only spaces, but obviously noam meant tab separated file. I just deleted the comment here.

Comment: @thanasisp it's not just you who needs the info that the input contains tabs though, e.g. see triplees answer and I started out only handling blanks til I happened to glance at naom42's comment here. That's important info that's missing from the question.

Comment: @Ed Morton that's true, I updated my answer, thanks.

Comment: When I pasted my input line from the terminal into the question, it didn't maintain the tabs and I couldn't figure out how to add them back in, so I resorted to adding a number of spaces (I should have mentioned "tabs", sorry about it).

Answer (score 2):

If, as in your example, the colon is not part of the string which should be preserved, try

```
sed 's/\(\(^\| \)[^ :][^ :][^ :]\)[^ :]*:[^ ]*/\1/g' file
```

The literal spaces in the character classes may need to be augmented with tabs and possibly other whitespace characters.

(The regex could be prettier if your `sed` supports extended regex with `-E` or `-r` or some such nonstandard option; but this ugly sucker should be portable most anywhere.)

Comment: I doubt using the `^` in a subexpression as an anchor is portable. And likely there is a typo in your `sed` expression. I think it should have been `s/\(\(^\| \)[^ :][^ :][^ :]\):[^ ]*/\1/g` or `s/\(\(^\| \)[^ :][^ :][^ :]\)[^ :]*:[^ ]*/\1/g`

Comment: Thanks; typo fixed. I haven't come across a `sed` which doesn't allow `^` inside a group, though I suppose this could be refactored into two separate cases (where on/y the latter requires `/g`).

Comment: There is no sed that doesn't allow `^` as the "start of string" anchor whether it's inside a capture group or not. It obviously has to be at the start of a capture group that can match at the start of the input string as you have it.

Answer (score 2):

Using a sed that has a `-E` are to enable EREs (e.g. GNU or BSD/OSX sed):

```
$ sed -E 's/([^[:space:]]{3}):[^[:space:]]+/\1/g' file
01    81118   9164.47    0/0   0/0  0/1
```

With a POSIX sed:

```
$ sed 's/\([^[:space:]]\{3\}\):[^[:space:]]\{1,\}/\1/g' file
01    81118   9164.47    0/0   0/0  0/1
```

The above will work regardless of whether the spaces in your input are blanks or tabs or both.

Comment: Very clean sed: However, and the assumption that we never know anything properly about the input, we could assume that if a tab is the designated FS, a space of any form could occur in a field with a colon. So the above would fail. But again, this is under the assumption we know nothing and we have to hyper-generalise the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/\S*:/\n&/g;s/\n(\S{3})\S*/\1/g;s/\n//g' file
```

Prepend a newline to any non-whitespaced strings which contains a `:`.

If these strings contain at least 3 non-whitespaced characters, remove all but the first 3 characters.

Clean up any strings with `:`'s which were not 3 non-whitespaced characters in length.

Answer (score 0):

- optional : set  **`_ = "[[:space:]]*"`** 
  if u wanna use the formal `POSIX` `regex` class

> ```
> echo "${input}" | 
>                    
> mawk 'BEGIN { __ = OFS ="\f\r\t"
>               FS = "^"(_ = "[ \t]*")"|(:"(_)")?"(_)
>                _ = sub("[(]..", "&^", FS) } $_ = __$_'
> ```

```
01
81118
9164.47
0/0
0/0
0/1
```

*tested and confirmed working on* `gawk 5.1.1`, `mawk 1.3.4`, `mawk 1.996`, *and* `macos nawk`

The ***ultra brute force*** method would be like :

> ```
> mawk NF=NF FS='(:[^ \t]*)?[ \t]*' OFS='\t'
> ```

```
01    81118    9164.47    0/0    0/0    0/1
```

to handle leading/trailing edge spaces+tabs in brute-force approach:

> ```
> gawk NF=NF FS='(:[^ \t]*)?[ \t]*' OFS='\t' | column -t
> ```

```
01  81118  9164.47  0/0  0/0  0/1
```